# Old jQuery functions running after being removed from code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is an odd one. At on point I had some javascript running that would check for a certain class existing or not on a page, and then creating an alert window. This was a few weeks ago, and I recall deleting the function shortly after creating it.

However, the function still runs every time I open pages that the function related to. I am using notepad++ and have been using the "find in files" ctrl+f function to find any instance of the aforementioned javascript code but I always come up empty handed. And yet, he function still runs. I have tried on multiple browsers and it happens in all of them, so it doesn't appear to be a browser cache issue.

I created a function, deleted it, found that it was still functioning, searched for its source and ultimately I cannot find where could possibly be coming from. Has anyone else encountered this, and is there a way to pinpoint where the javascript is running from?

Comment: It'l be in the dev tools.

Comment: it shouldn't be hard to find the code -- look for string constants in your alert, and then search the resources pane in the dev tools for such a string. The code is there.

Comment: You probably thought of that already, but: did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Maybe you are referencing a different file (same name, other location).